# Reading Excel Cells using C#

Tags: c#, excel

What's the way to open a excel workbook and to read excel cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380/) you will get details how to open and handle excel through C#.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us which part of that thread? We don't really like link only answers here and prefer your post to be able to stand on its own and where you provide the link for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx) to extend Office products with your code and [here's](http://www.packtpub.com/article/microsoft-office-excel-programming-using-vsto) a good tutorial to get you started in Excel programming

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source .NET library called [Koogra](http://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra/) for reading Excel files, both BIFF (older Excel) and XSLX (newer Excel). Otherwise you can use Excel automation, but I would avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [open xml sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en) to read (and write) excel files (in open xml format off course).   There is an [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd452407.aspx) describing how to use the open xml sdk.

A big advantage is that you don't have to install excel on the server (or client) to read excel files.